# Getting results from table that has 2 one-to-many relationships

Tags: django

In my application I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Talk(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    speaker = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_talk = models.DateField('date_of_talk')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    membership_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MEMBERSHIP_TYPES)
    membership_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name    
class Event_Attendance(models.Model):
    talk = models.ForeignKey('Talk')
    membersAttended = models.ForeignKey('Member')  
    def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s attended %s' %(unicode(self.membersAttended), unicode(self.talk))
```

And I want to be able to pull out all the results from the `Event_Attendance` model when i input a talk. This is so that i can get the names of the people that attended it. Every thing that I have tried has failed such as:

```
 a = Event_Attendance(talk="Meteors")
```

Has anyone else got any ideas?
Thanks in Advance,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think members_attended field in your EventAttendance model would be better as a ManyToManyField

```
class EventAttendance(models.Model):
    talk = models.ForeignKey(Talk)
    members_attended = models.ManyToManyField(Member)
```

That would make it easy to get the information you want.

Comment: I should also use through as i am managing the table "manually"